# LED control with a string variable

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega

I would like to control three LEDs with a string variable using an Arduino Mega.

I have connected the three LEDs to pins 10, 11 and 12 of the Arduino.

If my string equals Red, the red LED should turn on. If my string equals Yellow, the yellow LED should turn on. If my string equals Green, the green LED should turn on.

I wrote the following program, and I expect the following: When I type Red, I expect the Red LED to turn on, and so on for the others. But no LED turns on.

You can check the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MAnAc_t0OrM&t=1583s

```
int redPin=10, yellowPin=11, greenPin=12;

String my_Color;
String msg1="Which LED do you want to turn ON?";
String msg2="Red, Yellow or Green?";
String msg3="You chose LED:";

void setup() {
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yellowPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(greenPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(msg1);
  Serial.println(msg2);
  while(Serial.available()==0) {}
  my_Color=Serial.readString();
  Serial.print(msg3 );
  Serial.println(my_Color);
  Serial.println('Red', BIN);
  Serial.println('my_Color',BIN);
  if(my_Color == "Red") {
    Serial.print("Red True");
    digitalWrite(redPin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin,LOW);
  }
  if(my_Color=="Yellow") {
    digitalWrite(redPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowPin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenPin,LOW);
  }
  if(my_Color=="Green") {
    digitalWrite(redPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowPin,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenPin,HIGH);
  }
}
```

Could anyone check the sketch and correct me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question originated on electronics.stackexchange.com, copying my answer from there:

There are three main areas where your system may be failing: the LEDs, the string input, and the logic evaluations. Right now it's a black box - you enter some input, and you don't see an output. But you have no idea where the system is failing between those two points. You should first narrow down to find which one the problem is. This is very good practice for learning how to debug systems in general.

Start with the string input. After you read in the string from Serial, print it back out. Verify that it matches what you entered. (I expect this to be the problem. Like I said in my comment, your string is probably being read in as "Red\r \n ". Print the string twice, and if it prints "Red" twice with a line break in between, than that is your problem. You need to run my_Color.trim() to fix that.)

Then, check the logic evaluations. Add a Serial.print() command with some string in it after each **if** evaluation. If your program prints out the string after you enter a valid LED color, than you know that your code is executing correctly. If not, there is some difference between the my_color String and the String you are checking it against.

Thereafter, if it is still not working then the problem is with the LEDs. I don't have your circuit so I can't tell you what to debug there.

Comment: The program works as it is expected when I used the trim() function. Could you please explain to me why it needs the trim() function in this case ?

Comment: @learndesign: In the description of the video you linked to, there is a big warning written in all caps: “_GUYS MAKE SURE YOUR SERIAL MONITOR IS SET TO 'NO LINE ENDING'!!!_”. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: @learndesign there are certain special characters associated with the String data type. Two such characters are "\n" and "\r". When the '\' and 'r' or 'n' are next to each other in a string, they actually correspond to a line break (cursor moves down a line) and a carriage return (cursor moves all the way to the left of the current line). For a lot of serial monitors, when you enter a string, it automatically appends "\r\n" onto the end of the string, possibly with whitespace as well. Since "Red \r\n" != "Red", your if statements were never triggering. The trim() function removes that for you.